# I am getting an error message for a line that isnt there

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently making a discord bot in javascript but it wont run. Whenever i attemp to run it it shows this error message

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\--Discord robo--\bot.js:114
});
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:499:15)
```

it is saying the error is on line 114 but my code only has 113 lines. 
https://pastebin.com/AwEz01Nt

```
   var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');

});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`

    if (message.substring(0, 1, 2) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
        var in1 = args[1];}

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {


            // !ping
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong!'
                });
            break;


            // !commands
            case 'commands':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'The current commands are: ping, commands, random and rps and the current prefix is h.'
                });
            break;


            // !random
        case 'random':
        var randomnumber; // setting the randomnumber variable
        var upper;
        upper = in1 ;
        randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(in1));
        bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'Your random number from 1 to ' + in1 + ' is ' + randomnumber});
        break;


     // !rps
        case 'rps': //if the code is rps
            var in2;
            rpsrandom = Math.random();
            if ( rpsrandom <= 1/3 ) { in2 = 'rock' ;}
            if ( rpsrandom >= 2/3 ) {in2 = 'scissors' ;}
            else {in2 = 'paper';}
            bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: in2});
                if (in1 == 'r')//if in1 is rock
                { 
                    if (in2 == 'paper'){
                        bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'You lose!'});
                        break;
                    }
                    if (in2 == 'scissors'){
                        bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'You win!'});
                        break;
                    }
                    else {bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'It is a tie!'});
                    break;
                }
                if (in1 == 'p') //if in1 is rock
                { 
                    if (in2 == 'scissors'){
                        bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'You lose!'});
                        break;
                    }
                    if (in2 == 'rock'){
                        bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'You win!'});
                        break;
                    }
                    else {bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'It is a tie!'});
                    break;
                }
                if (in1 == 's')//if in1 is rock
                { 
                    if (in2 == 'rock'){
                        bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'You lose!'});
                        break;
                    }
                    if (in2 == 'paper'){
                        bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'You win!'});
                        break;
                    }
                    else {bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'It is a tie!'});
                    break;
                }
        break;  
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
    }
;
```

I am pretty new to java script and coding for a discord bot so i dont know why this won't work

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket on this line:
                    else {bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'It is a tie!'});

You never close the else.

Comment: But the line numbering not being correct might be because of your browser having cached copies of your files.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing parenthesis before the final semicolon

The last lines of your code should be

```
break;  
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
    }
);
```

Generally, your formatting is a mess and makes it very hard to spot such errors. Think about using an IDE with automatic formatting.

Comment: i have added that in and the error message hasn't changed apart from the error being on line 113 now

Comment: Also do you have any recommendations

Answer (score 1):

In both

`else {bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: 'It is a tie!'});`

lines there are missing closing brackets.

And please clean up that Code a bit, and you will find the errors all by yourself. :)